# How to call a custom function synchronously in node js?

Tags: node.js

I am developing a server project which needs to call some functions synchronously. Currently I am calling it in asynchronous nature. I found some similar questions on StackOverflow and I can't understand how to apply those solutions to my code. Yet I tried using **async/await** and ended up with an error `The 'await' operator can only be used in an 'async' function`

Here is my implementation

```
function findSuitableRoom(_lecturer, _sessionDay, _sessionTime, _sessionDuration, _sessionType){
                let assignedRoom = selectRoomByLevel(preferredRooms, lecturer.level, _sessionDuration); <------- Need to be call synchronously

                if (!assignedRoom.success){
                    let rooms = getRooms(_sessionType); <------- Need to be call synchronously
                    assignedRoom = assignRoom(_lecturer.rooms, _sessionDuration, _lecturer.level);
                } else {
                    arr_RemovedSessions.push(assignedRoom.removed)
                }

                return assignedRoom;
}
```

```
function getRooms(type){

    switch (type){
        case 'Tutorial' : type = 'Lecture hall'
                            break;

        case 'Practical' : type = 'Lab'
                            break;
        default : type = 'Lecture hall'
    }

    Rooms.find({type : type},
        (err, rooms) => {
            if (!err){
                console.log('retrieved rooms ' + rooms)
                return rooms;
            }
        })
}
```

Here I have provided only two methods because full implementation is very long and I feel if I could understand how to apply synchronous way to one method, I can manage the rest of the methods. Can someone please help me?

Comment: check my implementation, it will do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes `await` is only available inside an async function so put `async` infront of `findSuitableRoom`.

Also you did a classic mistake. You use `return` inside of a callback function, and expect `getRooms` to return you some value.

```
async function findSuitableRoom(
  _lecturer,
  _sessionDay,
  _sessionTime,
  _sessionDuration,
  _sessionType
) {
  let assignedRoom = selectRoomByLevel(
    preferredRooms,
    lecturer.level,
    _sessionDuration
  );

  if (!assignedRoom.success) {
    try {
      let rooms = await getRooms(_sessionType);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("no rooms found");
    }
    assignedRoom = assignRoom(
      _lecturer.rooms,
      _sessionDuration,
      _lecturer.level
    );
  } else {
    arr_RemovedSessions.push(assignedRoom.removed);
  }
  return assignedRoom;
}
```

Also wrap it in an `try / catch`

Since `.find()` returns an promise if you dont pass an callback you can write it like this

```
function getRooms(type) {
  switch (type) {
    case "Tutorial":
      type = "Lecture hall";
      break;

    case "Practical":
      type = "Lab";
      break;
    default:
      type = "Lecture hall";
  }
  return Rooms.find({ type });
}
```

Note here `findSuitableRoom` is no longer synchronouse. Its async and returns an promise. That means you will need to use the function like this:

`findSuitableRoom.then(res => { console.log(res); })`

Comment: I used the async keyword in front of the function in order to use await. But the error occurs

Comment: @SAMaster so you wrote ths `async function findSuitableRoom` and it still gives you an exact this error `The 'await' operator can only be used in an 'async' function` ?

Comment: Yeah I am still having exact same error even after changing the function as ```async function findSuitableRoom``` :( :( @Ifaruki

Comment: @SAMaster this cannot be. you sure you didnt make some other mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
The 'await' operator can only be used in an 'async' function
```

This means whenever you want to use the await keyword it needs to be inside a function which has an async keyword (returns promise)

read this `https://javascript.info/async-await` for more info

Answer (score 0):

```
const add = (a, b) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {   //to make it asynchronous
      if (a < 0 || b < 0) {
        return reject("don't need negative");
      }
      resolve(a + b);
    }, 2000);
  });
};


const jatin = async () => {
  try{
    const sum = await add(10, 5);
    const sum2 = await add(sum, -100);
    const sum3 = await add(sum2, 1000);
    return sum3;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
jatin()
```

Try this

let's understand this

- add is a normal function that does some asynchronous action like
  waiting for 2 seconds
- *normally we use await with async function so in order to use it we make as async function `jatin` and use await with add function call
  to make it synchronous, so until first `await add call()` doesn't
  happen it wont execute another `await add call()`.*

Example code if you will use in your app.js

```
         router.post("/users/login", async (req, res) => {
         try {
         const user = await User.findByCredentials(
          req.body.email,
          req.body.password
        );
        const token = await user.generateToken();
    
        res.status(200).send({
          user,
          token,
        });
      } 
        catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).send();
      }
    });
```

Comment: you should wrap the  `await`s in a try catch block

Comment: if it helped you accept it as a solution to your answer so that it may help others :)